# Equation Involving Digit Sum Function

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, decimal-expansion

Define the digit sum $S$ of a number as the sum of its digits. For example, $S(456)=4+5+6=15$. Given positive integers $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and $Q$, I'd like to ask how to obtain the nonnegative solutions to $S(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_i)=Q$ which minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the $a_i$ are large and the $x_i$ are small where rounding issues intervene, you want the sum to be the minimum number whose sum of digits is $Q$.  That will be a series of $9$s with a prefix digit for the remainder of dividing $Q$ by $9$. 
 Let $k=\lfloor \frac Q9 \rfloor, m=Q \bmod 9$.  Then $N=(m+1)10^k-1$ is the smallest number with sum of digits $Q$.  We therefore want the solution to
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_i=N$$
that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$.  This is a classic linear optimization problem.  Again, absent some strange things with the $a_i$, we will want to find the greatest $a_i$ and make $x_i$ large, then fix any rounding problem.